# Table within a SQL table

Tags: sql, arrays, sql-server

I have used this type of data storage in a VBA bsed application, storing a record, where one of the fields was an array. Is this possible on a SQL table?

eg. I need to store data relating to customers and their assets. Each client has their own list of assets. I would use a second joined table, but then each customer would require their own new table.
Is it possible to store this in an array within the original table?

Comment: _but then each customer would require their own new table_ - why?

Comment: You can use any number of tables, you need to define primary key and foreign key relationships for join conditions. Please tag your RDBMs are you using t-sql, mysql ?

Comment: @tarriq Pillay You don't need new table for each customer. store customer id in assets table and join tables

Comment: thanks for responses. Just to add, each asset in each list will be completely unique to each client. I could use a separate table and store all assets (referencing their customer) and then join? but that seems a little messy

Comment: @TarriqPillay that's the standard way to model 1-N relations in RDBMS. You'll need to join them using customer key.

Comment: it has finally permeated my thick head. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ... Although the SQL standard _does_ define how arrays are used, only very few DBMS products actually support that. But in most of the cases it's better to properly normalize the model rather than using arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If RDMS, you can either  use 
1) XML data type or JSON to maintain the asset information against each client 
 2)  OR create a separate table for assets and link to the client table.

It depends on individual use case and context.

1) if you are having only 1 or 2 assets to be maintained against each client. then XML/ JSON would be ideal.
2) if you maintaining high volumes of assets against each client, then the creation of separate table is ideal.
3)If you are unsure of the volume, then a separate table for an asset is ideal.

Comment: The SQL standard **does** define arrays (and some DBMS do implement them - quite efficiently in case of Postgres for example). But I do agree that the first approach should be a properly normalized model

Comment: It depends on the use case, sure, but you should place a normalized table layout as your first option. XML/JSON just opens a different can of worms (making queries more complex is the first thing that comes to mind). 95+/100 of the cases, should prefer a normalized table layount (I'd argue 99+%).